# EL1008E: Property or field 'user_id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public or not valid?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I cant solve this problem, i need some help

this is the .html code

```
                <tr data-th-each="user : ${Users}">
                    <td data-th-text="${Users.user_id}"></td>
                    <td data-th-text="${Users.user_name}"></td>
                    <td data-th-text="${Users.user_email}"></td>
                    <td data-th-text="${Users.user_telephone}"></td>
                    <td data-th-text="${Users.user_type}"></td>
                    <td data-th-text="${Users.user_available}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
    <br>
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="/newUser">Crear Usuario</a>
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="/">Volver</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the .java of user

```
    public Users() {
        super();
    }
    public Users(String user_id, String user_name, String user_email, String user_password, int user_telephone, String user_type, int user_available) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.user_email = user_email;
        this.user_password = user_password;
        this.user_telephone = user_telephone;
        this.user_type = user_type;
        this.user_available = user_available;
    }
    //Getters
    public String getUserId() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return user_name;
    }
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return user_email;
    }
    public String getUserPassword() {
        return user_password;
    }
    public int getUserTelephone() {
        return user_telephone;
    }
    public String getUserType() {
        return user_type;
    }
    public int getUserAvailable() {
        return user_available;
    }
}
```

ok this is all the code of user.java
what should i do to solve this error
its for a sprint project
but why i cant send this, lol

Comment: Can't you show the whole User.java ?

Comment: Your "Users" variable may be ArrayList. As you have already iterating and assigning each user to "user" variable, you need to use "user.userId" instead of "Users.user_id"

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this example

```
<table>
  <th:block th:each="user : ${users}">
    <tr>
       <td th:text="${user.login}"></td>
       <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
   </tr>
 </th:block>
</table>
```